# Why is my fetch function giving me a 400 bad request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I am trying to integrate the stripe checkout sessions in my React app. In order to create the session I have a node/express server running in the background that has a "/billing" post.

When I try to hit it using fetch I get a 400 bad request from my chrome console.

Here's the function in my frontend:

```
const submitReq = () =>{

  const price = {price: "price_1HmAziJIQLh7k5Y65s1Hyupc"};
  fetch("http://localhost:8282/billing", {
    method: "POST",
    redirect: "follow",
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(price),
  }).then(response => {
    if(response.ok){
    console.log(response);
    response.json()}
    else{ throw Error(`Request rejected with status ${response.status}`);}
  })
  .then(price =>{
    console.log('success:', price);
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.error("error:", error);
  });
}
```

Then in the node/express I have the "/billing" post which looks like this

```
app.options("/billing", cors(corsConfig));
app.post("/billing", async (req, res) => {
  const  {priceId}  = req.body;
  console.log(priceId);

 
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: "subscription",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [
        { 
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      
      success_url: 'https://example.com/success.html',
      cancel_url: 'https://example.com/canceled.html',
    });

    res.send({
      sessionId: session.id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Just above `res.status(400);` add `console.log(e)` - this will print the error. Also give `e` a real name, like `error`.

Comment: So it gives me a missing parameter error from the stripe API that I'm missing the currency, and if I give it the currency it tells me I am missing the amount. However, the priceId that stripe generates should contain both the amount to charge as well as the currency it is in. if I console.log my PriceId it gives me undefined, so it seems that my frontend isn't passing the req.body. If i don't destructure it however it passes just fine. Why is this?

Comment: So we've solved the reason why it gets 400. Not sure why re: destructuring. But that's a separate issue. In future, for StackOverflow: try and reduce the test case down. For example, you could have removed the `stripe.checkout.sessions.create` and found out that was the cause of the problem.